# C# custom unary operators overloading

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Does C# classes inherit custom operators from base classes? I'm trying the following code:

```
class Person
{
    public int Age;

    public static Person operator ++(Person p)
    {
        p.Age++;
        return p;
    }
}

class Agent : Person {   }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p = new Person { Age = 23 };
    Console.WriteLine ( "Before increment : {0}" , p.Age );

    p++;
    Console.WriteLine("After increment : {0}", p.Age);

    Agent agent = new Agent { Age = 25 };
    Console.WriteLine("Before increment : {0}", agent.Age);

    agent++;
    Console.WriteLine("After increment : {0}", agent.Age);

}
```

The compiler told me that he cannot explicitly convert from Person to Agent.

I tried :

```
Agent agent = new Agent();
Person person = agent ++
```

But the same compiler message appear.

Comment: In what line the error occurs?

Comment: Error occurs when i try to increment the 'agent' variable.

Comment: The title of your question does not seem to have anything to do with the content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [operator overloading and inheritance c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523613/operator-overloading-and-inheritance-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is not based on whether or not the operator is inherited but due to the return type of the operator.

However in the case of an assigning operator you will have an issue with the return type of the operator

The expression `x++` is a short hand for

```
x = x + 1
```

And in your case you are returning a `Person` and trying to assign that to an `Agent`.
Written out that would be

```
agent.Age++;
agent = (Person)agent; //the cast is implicit and a result of the return type
```

You can only assign to a more generalized type. So assigning an `Agent` to a `Person` would work which is why the compiler will allow the return type to be a specialization of the implementing type (as is the case below).

You can accomplish what you are looking for with a bit of generics trickery

```
class Person<T> where T : Person<T>, new()
{
    public int Age;

    //taking advantage of the fact that the return type might be a specialization
    //of the type implementing the operator
    public static T operator ++(Person<T> p)
    {
        return new T { Age = p.Age + 1 };   
    }
}

class Agent : Person<Agent> { }

//Only required if Person should be usable on it's own
class Person : Person<Person> { }
```

The above operator constructs a new object which to me is inline with the contract of the `++`operator but also requires a default constructor, if you wish you can do it with a cast instead.

```
public static T operator ++(Person<T> p)
{
    p.Age++;
    return (T)p;
}
```

Whether or not the operator is inherited is a matter of how you define inheritance.

The C# specifications uses "inheritance" in a different manner than the [CLI specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf). The way the C# specs uses inheritance is in the the context of operators and static methods incompatible with the CLI specification (Ie the C# spec contradict the CLI specifications and as such the platform C# runs on does not support the specifications)

To out line why my money is on "operators are not inherited" is that they are syntax sugar for a static method.

```
[SpecialName]
public static T op_increment(Person<T> p)
{
    return new T { Age = p.Age + 1 };   
}
```

That's the implementation of a static method. According to the CLI specifications then static methods are not inherited:

> A derived object type inherits all of the instance and virtual methods of its base object type. It 
>   does not inherit constructors or static methods.

below is an implementation of the `++` operator

```
public static T operator ++(Person<T> p)
{
    return new T { Age = p.Age + 1 };   
}
```

The IL for both of these two implementations is *identical*

Comment: Wrong, check out my answer

Comment: I tied "Person person = agent ++" and it didn't work.The compiler complain about the same conversion problem.

Comment: This isn't even valid C# code.  The parameter type of a unary operator must be the _containing type_ (in this case, `Person<T>`, not `T`).  The code in this answer won't actually compile.

Comment: @RuneFS It is defined, check out my answer with relevant link.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you have linked to c++ specifications

Comment: "In this particular case the ++ operator (or any other operator) wouldn't be legal as a part of the derived type." => It's not legal _at all_.  That code _does not compile_.

Comment: @RuneFS Earlier I wrongly linked c++, now check my updated answer, not comments. [c# Language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @MikeStrobel You are correct that the compiler will complain about the  parameter type, though it's an easy fix since all T are also `Person<T>` doesn't really changes the general idea

Comment: @RuneFS Well, the code in your latest update compiles, so you can remove the bit about the error in your last paragraph.  Your solution, however, does render the `Person` type unusable on its own in that you can no longer have a declaration like `Person p = ...`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel correct then you'd need to do `class Person : Person<Person> {}` and then you can use Person un it's own

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The C# specifications uses `inheritance` differently than the CLI specifications and in the context of the CLI specifications the C# specification is _wrong_ (see the edit)

Comment: @RuneFS I tried "Person person = agent ++" and it didn't work.

Comment: @BrahimBoulkriat no and it shouldn't. That short hand for `agent.Age++; agent = (Person)agent; Person person = agent;` and the first assignment is invalid. `agent.Age++` would of course work

Answer (score 2):

Operators are implemented as static and inheritance does not apply to static members.

Some operators will work with derived types, some will not. It is a matter of type conversion rules.

But basically, `Person p = ...; p++;` is a very bad idea anyway. When you use operator overloading where it is appropriate you won't run into problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

> Like other members, operators declared in a base class are inherited by derived classes. Because operator declarations always require the class or struct in which the operator is declared to participate in the signature of the operator, it is not possible for an operator declared in a derived class to hide an operator declared in a base class. Thus, the new modifier is never required, and therefore never permitted, in an operator declaration.

Above quote from [c# Language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

---

It does, Compiler checks to see any operator overloading defined in inheritance hierarchy. If found it uses that

Consider the following code

```
class Person
{
    public int Age;
    public static int operator +(Person p, Person p2)
    {
        return p.Age + p2.Age;
    }
}
class Agent : Person
{

}
static void Main()
{
    Person p = new Person { Age = 23 };
    Agent agent = new Agent { Age = 25 };

    int res = p + agent;//Result 48
    Console.WriteLine("Result is "+ res);
}
```

In your case compiler found `++` operator and tries to use it, but the problem is with return type. It returns base type, so it won't work. It can't be assigned to more derived type.

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/YshrhR)

Comment: Does Agent inherit the custom operator?

Comment: No, the operator is not inherited. The operands are converted.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is inherited. All operators except(**=**) are inherited. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4x88tzx0.aspx) check the 9th bullet

Comment: @BrahimBoulkriat Yes it is inherits. Check it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4x88tzx0.aspx)

Comment: What about modifying the custom + operator so it takes a Perosn and an Agent as arguments and adding two agent together?Does it upcast Agent to Person and return a Person?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - A very relevant link, if this had been about C++ ... . But it isn't, and operators are not inherited.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel This is a link about operator overloading in C++.

Comment: The debate over the semantics of "inheritance" and whether static members are technically inherited is rather pointless.  It's pretty clear from the question that the OP was asking if user-defined operators declared on a base type could be _applied_ to a subtype.

Comment: Sorry about the link, but as you can see compiler will apply. As @MikeStrobel said *If you ask whether custom operators defined in base class is applicable for derived classes are not?* **Then answer is yes, they do**

Comment: @BrahimBoulkriat In answer to the question in your comment, it depends on the return type of the `+` operator you define.  Operator resolution depends on the operand types; whoever implements the chosen operator gets to determine how it works, e.g., if casting occurs and what the return type is.  If you wanted to implement `static operator + Agent(Agent a, Person p) { a.Age += p.Age; return a; }`, or something similar, then you certainly could, though that would really break the contract of the `+` operator, which is supposed to be pure with respect to the operands (it should not modify them).

Comment: @MikeStrobel I tried 'Person p = agent++' and it didn't work.

Comment: @BrahimBoulkriat It didn't work for the same reason `agent++` didn't work in your original question.  It's not going to start working just because you put an assignment on the left hand side; it's still going to update `agent` with the result of the `++` operator.

Comment: @BrahimBoulkriat Updated the relevant link, check it out

Comment: @SriramSakthivel In your naswer you used the + operator.But a i'am talking about the ++ operator.I tried 'Person p = agent++' and it didn't work as well.The compiler told me that he cannot explicitly convert from Person to Agent although i assigned 'agent++' to 'Person p'.

Comment: @BrahimBoulkriat See the last paragraph in my answer I explained why that doesn't work

Comment: @SriramSakthivel In your answer you are talking about assigning agent++ to a variable of type Agent.I'am talking about assigning agent++ to a variable of type Person.It result in the same compiler error.

Comment: @BrahimBoulkriat `agent++ to a variable of type Person` will first increments the agent then assigns it to `agent` back then it will assign it to Person variable. So `agent++` not allowed

Answer (score 0):

The ugly/pretty but not so generic solution:

```
class Agent : Person 
{
    public static Agent operator ++(Agent p)
    {
        p.Age++;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you *could* go with something like

```
class Person
{
    public int Age;
    public static T IncrementAge<T>(T p) where T : Person
    {
        p.Age++;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the following doesn't work:

```
    public static T operator ++<T>(T p) where T : Person
    {
        p.Age++;
        return p;
    }
```

The straight forward way would probably rather be this one, though:

```
    public void IncrementAge()
    {
        Age++;
    }
```