# Why do C# 9 records lose structural equality when compared through operator from behind interfaces?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

If one tries to equate two records where the statically known types are just an interface implemented by the records, AND does so using the equality operator `==`, the structural equality check is lost.

Casting to a concrete type (not always possibly statically..) or directly calling the .Equals method returns the expected structural comparison result.

As seen in the following example:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/An2MrN

whose contents:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public interface IProblem {
    }
    
    public record Jank(string name) : IProblem;
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        IProblem a = new Jank("x");
        IProblem b = new Jank("x");
        Console.WriteLine("a == b: " + (a == b));
        Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(b): " + a.Equals(b));
        Console.WriteLine("((Jank)a == (Jank)b): " + ((Jank)a == (Jank)b));
    }
}
```

and its output:

```
a == b: False
a.Equals(b): True
((Jank)a == (Jank)b): True
```

Is this by design? or just a teething problem? If by design, why design it so?

Comment: This seems necessary because you can't know that the interface is a record? The underlying concrete could be a normal class

Comment: I mean sure, but I don't need to know it either way. In fact, the first check the records generated structural equality check does is a dynamic type check to see if both records are the same concrete type.

Comment: Because by default `==` is reference equality for non-value types (of which an interface is, even when implemented by a struct) and because operators are static there's no virtual dispatch or anything to force it to be anything *other* than a reference check

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood records are just classes with few additional methods, one of them is `==` and `!=` operator overload

this is `==` operator generated by the compiler:

[image]

you can create the same case with a class e.g.:

```
void Main()
{
    MyClass m1 = new();
    MyClass m2 = new();

    Console.WriteLine($"m1 == m2 {m1 == m2}");
    Console.WriteLine($"m1 == m2 {(IFoo)m1 == (IFoo)m2}");
}

class MyClass : IFoo
{
    public static bool operator ==(MyClass a, MyClass b) => true;

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass a, MyClass b) => false;
}

interface IFoo
{

}
```

output:

```
m1 == m2 True
m1 == m2 False
```

"The implementation of the operator is chosen at compile time. Operators are not virtual methods- the child class's == operator does not override the parent class == operator." copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523707/13176259) answer

Because interface operator was not overloaded the default `object` operator is used comparing them by reference.